# Minimize number of groups such that each group has at most k skill difference

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

We have a skills array where skills[i] denotes the skill of the ith student. We are trying to from groups such that the maximum skill difference between any 2 individuals within the same group is at most k. Find the minimum number of groups required to achieve this.

Example:

```
skills = [7,2,9,1,13,4]

k = 3

#min groups required = 3
groups = ([1,2,4] , [7,9], [13])
```

I can implement this very easily in O(n logn) by sorting it and then simply iterating and checking if we still meet the condition of at most k or else form a new group.

However, I am looking for a more efficient solution in O(n).

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to post either your attempt at finding such a solution, or explaining why you think one exists.

Comment: I believe this can be solved in O(ng), where g is the number of groups, but g could be O(n), making for a *slower* algorithm than the one you describe.

Comment: If *skill* is bounded than you can use a Radix sort or a Counting sort to sort in O(n), thus you will have a solution in O(n).